# Wrap/Reuse/Clone a PHP object (code optimization)

Tags: php, oop, optimization

Imagine two classes which share almost the same exact methods and properties, both extending a parent class, but the differences are minimal.

```
class fields { 
 public function __construct() {
  global $id;
  $this->id = $id++;
 }
}

class input extends fields {
 public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
 }
 public function draw() {
  echo '<input>';
 }
}

class textarea extends fields {
 public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
 }
 public function draw() {
  echo '<textarea>';
 }
}
```

I'm thinking it would be more efficient to rewrite the textarea class in this psuedo-code fashion:

```
class textarea extends fields {
 public function __construct() {
  $this = new input(); // <<------ 
 }
 public function draw() {
  echo '<textarea>';
 }
}
```

Basically, I'm unsure how this would best be done so that the class acts like the class from the first example.

In essence, I would like to do the following using OOP, but be able to use the object as it can be in the first example above (be able to call the possibly overloaded methods, have different properties, etc.):

```
function a() {echo '123';}
function b() {a();}
```

I have just copied the entire class and modify a few lines, but I feel it is wasteful.

**Final Answer**
Thanks to those people, here is the combined answer with example calls:

```
abstract class fields { 
 private static $masterid = 0;
 public function __construct() {
  $this->id = self::$masterid++;
 }
}

class input extends fields {
 public $data;
 public function __construct($new = '') {
  parent::__construct();
  if ($new) $this->data = $new;
  else $this->data = 'Hello';
 }
 public function draw() {
  echo '<input>'.$this->export().'</input>';
 }
 public function export() {
  return 'ID '.$this->id.' = '.$this->data;
 }
}

class textarea extends input {
 public function __construct($new = '') {
  parent::__construct($new);
 }
 public function draw() {
  echo '<textarea>'.$this->export().'</textarea>';
 }
}

$a = new textarea();
$a->draw();
$a = new textarea('World');
$a->draw();
$a = new input('!');
$a->draw();

//Outputs:
// <textarea>ID 0 = Hello</textarea>
// <textarea>ID 1 = World</textarea>
// <input>ID 2 = !</input>
```

Comment: you cant assign values to the $this reference.. sadly lol.  Anyway, can you describe how this will be used?

Comment: This is a very simple version of a theme form generator. I'm not looking to optimize this code above, as it is representative and shouldn't be considered. I'm trying to describe the concept of what I'd like to accomplish. Basically, wrap an object and still use be able to call the common methods and access the common properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the fields class an abstract class, and like Darren suggested, make the 'draw' method a function of the fields class.

Now heres the trick, you want the input class to extend fields, but override the draw method.  This will allow you to customize the functionality of that method, and you can still call the parent variation from within it.

Finally, since the textarea class is going to have many similarities to the input class, make textarea extend input.  Thereby inheriting the properties and methods of both fields and input.

Comment: I guess making it abstract would be the right way to go, but if you just wanted to echo something I don't it'd be necessary, but this script is pointless just like that, so I'd imagine there'd be a much more complex draw method than what I listed. I haven't done PHP forever, did you notice any errors in my syntax?

Comment: Well, it depends on how far he is going to go with building a library for what i can guess will be used to render UI components.  If he plans to make it complex, multiple layers of inheritance will help him.  Regarding your syntax, i did notice a missing semi-colon, and although it doesnt negatively effect the script, class properties should have access modifiers, and constructors dont usually need to be declared public, just better practice really.

Comment: I think that is the answer (the last paragraph), just have textarea extend input and overload as needed. Trying this with my more more complex code.

Comment: Correct, I should be saying method overriding.

Comment: sorry i deleted that comment since there is actually a system of overloading in php, just not the same way an other languages though

Comment: Yeah, I looked in to PHP Overloading and it was completely foreign to me. While looking in to whether it would be called Polymorphism, the PHP example on the wikipedia page looks exactly like method overriding, but says that it is not the same thing. I supposed it is merely an example of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Make the "fields" class have a draw method:

```
public function draw($msg) {
    echo $msg;
}
```

Then in the textarea or input class put:

```
parent::draw("<input>");
```

This cuts down on the number of methods you have, and can call one method for both types of field.

Also in your "fields" class, change the id code to be like this:

```
public $id
public function __construct($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}
```

Then in the subclass:

```
parent::__construct(1); //Or whatever ID you want
```

The way you have it, ID is the same value every time you set it, which will result in every subclass of fields having the same id. This way each subclass will have a seperate ID.

Also because I'm nice, here's it all put together:

```
public class field {
    $id;
    public __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function draw($msg) {
        echo $msg;
    }
}

public class input extends field {
    public __construct() {
        parent::__construct(1);
        parent::draw("<input>");
    }
}

public class textarea extends field {
    public __construct() {
        parent::__construct(2);
        parent::draw("<textarea>");
    }
}
```

That's how I'd put it together from what you've said. I may have mistaken what you were asking for though. Can you tell I'm primarily a Java programmer from that?

Comment: This answer won't ensure that id's are unique. Also, your calling parent::draw() from each child constructor. I don't think this is the intended behaviour.

Comment: Who voted this up? It doesn't work and it introduces magic numbers, which is bad!

Comment: Sorry, I'm extremely rusty on PHP, haven't done it almost a year probably. I'm too used to Java now.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the real code, the fields class does have a draw class, but it is both overloaded and called via parent::draw as needed in the child classes. I'm not looking to optimize the code above, I'm trying to describe the concept of what I'd like to accomplish. Basically, wrap an object and still use be able to call the common methods and access the common properties.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you want to do. For the example you've given, I think the structure is OK, but you should make a few changes, particularly with the constructor. I think the constructor should be abstract, with an abstract method draw().

```
abstract class fields { 

   // Use a static member to keep track of id's instead of making it global
   private static $id = 0;

   // Use an instance variable to keep track of a particular instance's id
   private $myId;

   public function __construct() {
      // Increment the static ID & assign it to the instance id.
      $this->myId = self::$id++;
   }

   // Provide a public getter, so that the ID can't be changed
   // externally to this class
   public function getId() {
       return $this->myId;
   }

   public abstract draw(); // Make sure all sub classes implement a draw() method.

}

class input extends fields {
   // Don't need to call the parent constructor if you're not adding anything
   // else. It will be called automatically.

   public function draw() {
      echo '<input>';
   }
}

class textarea extends fields {
   public function draw() {
      echo '<textarea>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The example is extremely pared down, the constructors are needed since each child class has different properties and accepts different attributes. Unfortunately, this doesn't hit on what I was asking, but I appreciate what you mentioned concerning the setting of internal and uneditable IDs.